# Setting the Zone in IE when serving pages from a CD

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

The software I am currently working on generates a set of web pages which can then be burnt to CD or DVD with an autorun tool, which launches the default browser.

The newest version includes a javascript routine to display images when the thumbnails are clicked.

This works fine when the pages are uploaded to a web server,  but when run locally IE blocks the javascript and asks the user for confirmation.

I have looked at ["Mark of the Web"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but that seems to break all the simple links on the page.

Is there another way to force html pages from a local drive to be treated as it they were on a web site (other than by telling the customers to use a proper web browser rather than IE).